# checking chrome extension is installed or not using Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a page in wocommerce which accept payment using Iwallet and i want to check whether the current user has that extension installed on chrome or not.

I have tried these script but not working.

```
<script>
var id = "kncchdigobghenbbaddojjnnaogfppfj";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(id, {action: "id", value : id}, function(response) {
    if(response && (response.id == id)) //extension installed
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
    else //extension not installed
    {
        console.log("Please consider installig extension");
    }
});
</script>
```

Then I tried Second one which is working but in both cases, it says not installed

```
function Ext_Detect_NotInstalled(ExtName, ExtID) {
  console.log(ExtName + ' Not Installed');
  if (divAnnounce.innerHTML != '')
    divAnnounce.innerHTML = divAnnounce.innerHTML + "<BR>"

  divAnnounce.innerHTML = divAnnounce.innerHTML + 'Page needs ' + ExtName + ' Extension -- to intall the LocalLinks extension click <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/' + ExtID + '">here</a>';
}

function Ext_Detect_Installed(ExtName, ExtID) {
  console.log(ExtName + ' Installed');
}

var Ext_Detect = function (ExtName, ExtID) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.onload = function () { Ext_Detect_Installed(ExtName, ExtID); };
  s.onerror = function () { Ext_Detect_NotInstalled(ExtName, ExtID); };
  s.src = 'chrome-extension://' + ExtID + '/manifest.json';
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}

var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

if (is_chrome == true) {
  window.onload = function () { Ext_Detect('LocalLinks', 'jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida'); };
}
```

Help me out how can I check the chrome for extension using Jquery.?
how can I use chrome.runtime.sendMessage and other function using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. That's because if such a thing was actually present it will be a privacy issue for the chrome users. Actually the chrome web store is the only website that has access to such a chrome api.

**BUT** - Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lucusfly/iost-extension) of the extension you can check what the extension is altering in you browser or even which messages its listening to.

In the Iwallet source code I found in content-script.js and inpage.js that it sets a special window object property window.IWalletJS and you can simply check if it exist to determine if the extension is installed or not.

As simple as:

```
if('IWalletJS' in window){
    console.log("IWallet is installed", window.IWalletJS);
} else {
    console.log("IWallet is not installed");
}
```

Take a look at the object attached to this property you can check if the user is logged, account name and more.

Hope I helped.